# MacBook Air 2012 Mini DisplayPort not working with HDTV

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport, hdmi, television

I'm trying to connect my 2012 11" MacBook Air to my Panasonic p60st60 1080p plasma HDTV using a new [Monoprice Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?p_id=5311&seq=1&format=2) & [6' HDMI cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10240&cs_id=1024008&p_id=3992&seq=1&format=2).

My TV displays a "No signal" message and my Mac does not show a secondary display option under System Preferences > Displays. I thought it was a handshake issue so I turned off the TV and Mac, turned on the TV, turned on the Mac, but the problem persists.

Any ideas to get this working? Thank you.

Comment: Neither screen flashes when I connect the Mini DisplayPort.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly same set up down to the MBA 2012 + Adapter and Cable.

It has been working flawlessly since.

So far I used it on 3 different TV models.

In your case I would say it is the adapter, they tend to be flaky (what do you expect for $6).

But, you can take a look in the Console and see what the "Windoserver" is doing when you plug in the cable.

If you live in the USA, go to store like Best buy or Walmart, get another adapter and try it. If it works you have your proof. If it does not just return it to the store for full refund.

Answer (score 0):

What happens to me sometimes is that it seems like it is connected yet applying a little more pressure will start the connection. depending on your tv "no signal" might switch to "detecting" stop applying pressure and enjoy your tv. I have research a lot and it seems as if the OS will get confuse easily before buying a new cable or adapter try testing them if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unplug it and replug it. May take more than a few attempts but give it 5 seconds or so before trying again. Problem still happens even on later models.